# List View based on current logged in user criteria

Tags: customsetting, list-view, app

I am creating an app where there should be a list view of users of that org. I have created a custom object which looks up to the User object. Based on some criteria of the current logged in user for example gender of the user(custom field in custom object), I want a list view to show users of that gender only. And there can be other criteria too.

So what are the ways to achieve this type of scenario?

I am still new to Salesforce. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not compare the value of two fields in the list view filter, It only supports values. But, you can create a list using a custom lightning page and custom lightning component with `lightning-datatable`. You will need to query the data based on the logged-in users' gender.

You have two options for implementation, Aura, and LWC.

Check out the lightning datatable docs [Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example) | [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable)

Comment: okay thanks. You sure there is no declarative approach?

Comment: yes. as of now. @RijulGanguly

Comment: okay. I'll look at lwc.